# Is there a name for HTTP headers that have multiple sections separated by semicolon?

Tags: http

I know that some HTTP headers that use `;` to delimit a series of values.

Some, like `Prefer`, define a repeating set of name-value pairs:

```
     Prefer     = "Prefer" ":" 1#preference
     preference = token [ BWS "=" BWS word ]
                  *( OWS ";" [ OWS parameter ] )
     parameter  = token [ BWS "=" BWS word ]
```

Others, like `Content-Type`, use a variant where there is an initial section with a value followed by optional name-value pairs (still separated by a `;`):

```
       Accept         = "Accept" ":"
                        #( media-range [ accept-params ] )
       media-range    = ( "*/*"
                        | ( type "/" "*" )
                        | ( type "/" subtype )
                        ) *( ";" parameter )
       accept-params  = ";" "q" "=" qvalue *( accept-extension )
       accept-extension = ";" token [ "=" ( token | quoted-string ) ]
```

I am writing some code to deal with this format in header values and I want to name it right (or at least well). I guess each header just does its own thing, but it would be handy to have a common for those "sections"/"components"/"name-value pairs".

Do various web frameworks have a common name for these?  Maybe just call them header value components and so the headers that define these can be "multi-component headers"?

Answer (score 1):

The closes thing to that used in the specs is "parameter".